# In this case, should I use the present progressive as a noun or infinitive as a noun?

Tags: verbs, nouns

"the only internal change McMurphy undergoes is becoming inwardly defeated", or "...to become inwardly defeated"?

Comment: Either one is correct. But may be used in cleft sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Both are okay . . . but . . .
(1) Here the use of "becoming" as a gerund does show a sense of "becoming" or "change;"
(2) the use of the infinitive "to become" implies something that is more complete.
However, I would add the pronoun "that" and a modal before "undergoes" and use "become" as an infinitive. So, add either "might" or 'will."

That reads clearer:
"The only internal change that McMurphy might undergo is to become inwardly defeated."
"The only internal change that McMurphy will undergo is to become inwardly defeated."